# Login with twitter; Getting http_code of 0

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have this code to enable login with twitter in my site

```
<?php
require("twitter/twitteroauth.php");
require 'config/twconfig.php'; //CONTAINS CONSUMER SECRET AND CONSUMER KEY
session_start();

$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$twitteroauth->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://MY WEBSITE URL');

// Saving them into the session

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

// If everything goes well..
if ($twitteroauth->http_code == 200) {
    // Let's generate the URL and redirect
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
} else {
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
    die('Something wrong happened.'.$twitteroauth->http_code);
}
?>
```

I am using Abraham Williams twitter oauth. This worked well for a couple of weeks, but now
am getting a http_code of 0, which is not even listed in twitters list of error codes.
What could be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is snippted i am using which works fine.

First make sure of the follownig
In dev twitter, you app can read / write
Refresh consumer key, Recreate access token.

If the folling is not working, the problem lies elsewhere t is something else!
see https://dev.twitter.com/search/apachesolr_search/HTTP%20CODE%200

Please read instructions, FOLLOW THEM and YOUR CODE will WORK

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');  
session_start();  
/* 
 * INSTRUCTIONS!!!
 * https://dev.twitter.com/
 * create app
 * https://dev.twitter.com/ TAB settings 
 * website: THE_URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT_WITH_THIS_CODE
 * callback_url http://www.YOURDOMAIN.COM/ 
 * Read, Write and Access direct messages ! 
 * Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter 
 * GO BACK TO DETAILS RECREATE / REFRESH - ACCESS TOKEN! 
 */

$consumerKey = '******************';
$consumerSecret = '******************';
$oAuthToken = '*********************';
$oAuthSecret = '**************************';

// The TwitterOAuth instance  
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);  
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to  
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://DOMAIN.com/YOURLOGINSCRIPT.php');  

// Saving them into the session  
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];  
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];  

// If everything goes well..  
if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){  
    // Let's generate the URL and redirect  
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header('Location: '. $url);
} else { 
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.  
    die('Something wrong happened.');  
}  
?>
```

Comment: problem must be with my twitter app because I tried using [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net)  and still got http code 0. Already refreshed my keys. Will use fb and google login for now

Comment: Make sure you have read / write permissions.. and recreate tokens. After that try code as i posted. from localhost / online if you can send a tweet, means all is good!

Comment: Also see the differance in your code and my snippet `$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET);` and my snippet `$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret); /* has the oAuthToken and oAuthSecret */`

Comment: I have edited my previous answer -- with the full code, almost the same as you , and it works absolutely fine